# Extjs4 hasMany() relationship not loading from Store's 'data' property

Tags: model, extjs4, extjs

The data property of my Extjs4 Store class describes an object hierarchy.  I put this as the data property of my store because the data is static; there's no need to make an extra call to the server to populate the store.  I've done this before, but this time my hasMany relationship isn't getting populated.  I've tried a variety of ways to fix this, but I'm stumped. Would you take a look at it to see if I'm missing something?

The relationship of objects is:  `MarineForm has MarineFormSections which has MarineFormFields`

**The store with it's data property**:

```
Ext.define('MAP.store.MarineFormStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MAP.model.MarineForm',
    data:[
        {
            species:'Mackerel',
            gear:null,
            sections:[
                {
                    name:'General Info',
                    formFields:[
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name:'firstField',
                            allowBlank:false,
                            fieldLabel:'First Field'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

**The root model**:

```
Ext.define('MAP.model.MarineForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {name: 'species', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'gear', type: 'string'}
    ],

    hasMany: {
        model: 'MAP.model.MarineFormSection',
        name: 'sections'
    }

});
```

**The hasMany class**:

```
Ext.define('MAP.model.MarineFormSection', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        'id',
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ],

    hasMany: {
        model: 'MAP.model.MarineFormField',
        name: 'formFields'
    }

});
```

**the hasMany's hasMany class (third layer nested)**

```
Ext.define('MAP.model.MarineFormField', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        'name',
        {name:'allowBlank', type:'boolean'},
        'fieldLabel',
        'xtype',
        //next ones are for comboboxes. Not used all the time. -jg
        'store',
        'valueField',
        'displayField'
    ]
});
```

Here's the output from querying the store within Chrome:

```
rootStore = Ext.getStore('MarineFormStore') // -> the store
sections = rootStore.getAt(0).sections() // -> hasMany store
sections.getCount() // -> 0
```

I've tried:

1. Removing the `MarineFormField hasMany` block for `MarineFormFields`
2. Adding an id to the `MarineFormField`
3. Triple checking for any typos in the the root store's `data` field

Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear to me that all you are missing is this in your store config (or unlikely you just forgot to load the store):

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
    }
},
```

[This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/NRQwd/1/) is pretty much your code with this change included and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for saving me some pain and sorrow.